# I have this weird plane showing up when I render an animation, but its fine in the viewport

Tags: rendering

It also disappears after 20 or so rendered frames
[image: Animation Render]

[image: Viewport Render]

Comment: Did you try looking in the outliner to see if you find the plane object?
You can try pressing alt+H to see if it's hidden (might be hidden but still renderable).

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing hidden other than a bezier curve I had hidden because it was in my way and I kept clicking it.

Comment: Very weird. If you share your blend file might be easier to try to find out what's going on.

Comment: I found out there was a model either not loaded or somehow hidden even when I unhide everything, because I found a plane after looking through everything, but it was invisible even when I were to hide/unhide